# Evaluating Polish Prefix Notation and Polish Postfix Notation

Tags: python, parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, math-expression-eval

In Polish postfix notation, the operators follow their operands. For example, to add 3 and 4 together, the expression is 3 4 + rather than 3 + 4. The conventional notation expression 3 − 4 + 5 becomes 3 4 − 5 + in Polish postfix notation: 4 is first subtracted from 3, then 5 is added to it.

Polish prefix notation, on the other hand, require that its operators precede the operands they work on. 3 + 4 would then be as + 3 4.

The algorithm used for parsing the postfix expression is simple:

```
while not end of file
    read token into var
  
    if (var is num)
        push var
    else if (var is operator) 
        if (operands >= 2)
            pop into rhs
            pop into lhs
            push lhs operator rhs
        else 
            throw exception
    else
        return fail
pop into var
return var
```

The code uses a stack to implement it. Prefix notation is parsed in the same manner, except that the tokens are reversed and the operands are swapped for each operation.

Parentheses are not supported.

### Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from typing import Union  # For older Python versions.

OPCODES = {
    "+": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs + rhs,
    "-": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs - rhs,
    "*": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs * rhs,
    "/": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs / rhs,
    "//": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs // rhs,
    "%": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs % rhs,
    "^": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs ** rhs,
}


def _eval_op(
    lhs: Union[int, float], rhs: Union[int, float], opcode: str
) -> Union[int, float]:
    return OPCODES[opcode](lhs, rhs)


def eval_postfix_expr(expr: str) -> Union[int, float]:
    """
    Evaluate a postfix expression.

    Supported operators:
        - Addition (+)
        - Subtraction (-)
        - Multiplication (*)
        - Division (/)
        - Floor Division (//)
        - Modulo (%)
        - Exponentiation (^)

    Raises:
        ValueError: If 'expr' is an invalid postfix expression.
    """
    tokens = expr.split()

    if tokens[-1] not in OPCODES.keys() or not tokens[0].isdigit():
        raise ValueError("Invalid expression.")

    stack = []

    for tok in tokens:
        if tok.isdigit():
            stack.append(int(tok))
        elif tok in OPCODES.keys():
            if len(stack) >= 2:
                rhs = stack.pop()
                lhs = stack.pop()
                stack.append(_eval_op(lhs, rhs, tok))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid expression.")

    return stack.pop()


def eval_prefix_expr(expr: str) -> Union[int, float]:
    """
    Evaluate a prefix expression.

    Supported operators:
        - Addition (+)
        - Subtraction (-)
        - Multiplication (*)
        - Division (/)
        - Floor Division (//)
        - Modulo (%)
        - Exponentiation (^)

    Raises:
        ValueError: If 'expr' is an invalid prefix expression.
    """
    tokens = expr.split()

    if tokens[0] not in OPCODES.keys() or not tokens[-1].isdigit():
        raise ValueError("Invalid expression.")

    tokens = reversed(tokens)
    stack = []

    for tok in tokens:
        if tok.isdigit():
            stack.append(int(tok))
        elif tok in OPCODES.keys():
            if len(stack) >= 2:
                lhs = stack.pop()
                rhs = stack.pop()
                stack.append(_eval_op(lhs, rhs, tok))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid expression.")

    return stack.pop()


def run_tests(func, test_data) -> None:
    func_len = len(func.__name__)
    max_expr_len = max(len(repr(expr)) for expr, _ in test_data)

    for expr, res in test_data:
        func_name = func.__name__
        expr_repr = repr(expr)
        print(
            f"func: {func_name:<{func_len}}, expr: {expr_repr:<{max_expr_len}}",
            end="",
        )
        try:
            rv = func(expr)
            assert rv == res, f"Expected: {res}, Received: {rv}"
        except Exception as e:
            rv = e
        print(f", result: {repr(rv)}")


def main() -> None:
    post_test_data = [
        ("3 4 +", 7),
        ("3 4 + 5 4 ^ +", 632),
        ("+ 10a 29", 0),
        ("10 5 * 6 2 + /", 6.25),
        ("10 7 2 3 * + -", -3),
        ("icaoscasjcs", 0),
        ("* 10 5 * 7 3 + // 2 -", 3),
    ]

    pre_test_data = [
        ("+ 3 4", 7),
        ("+ ^ 5 4 + 3 4", 632),
        ("+ 10a 29", 0),
        ("/ * 10 5 + 6 2", 6.25),
        ("- 10 + 7 * 2 3", -3),
        ("icaoscasjcs", 0),
        ("1038 - // * 10 5 + 7 3 2", 3),
    ]

    run_tests(eval_postfix_expr, post_test_data)
    print()
    run_tests(eval_prefix_expr, pre_test_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: '3 4 +'                , result: 7
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: '3 4 + 5 4 ^ +'        , result: 632
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: '+ 10a 29'             , result: ValueError('Invalid expression.')
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: '10 5 * 6 2 + /'       , result: 6.25
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: '10 7 2 3 * + -'       , result: -3
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: 'icaoscasjcs'          , result: ValueError('Invalid expression.')
func: eval_postfix_expr, expr: '* 10 5 * 7 3 + // 2 -', result: ValueError('Invalid expression.')

func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: '+ 3 4'                   , result: 7
func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: '+ ^ 5 4 + 3 4'           , result: 632
func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: '+ 10a 29'                , result: ValueError('Invalid expression.')
func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: '/ * 10 5 + 6 2'          , result: 6.25
func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: '- 10 + 7 * 2 3'          , result: -3
func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: 'icaoscasjcs'             , result: ValueError('Invalid expression.')
func: eval_prefix_expr, expr: '1038 - // * 10 5 + 7 3 2', result: ValueError('Invalid expression.')
```

### Review Request:

There's some duplication in the docstrings. How can that be helped?

Are there any bugs in my code? Did I miss something?

I should have liked to implement `eval_prefix_expr()` with `eval_postfix_expr()`, but I did not see a way to swap the operands for each operator. Do you?

General coding comments, style, naming, et cetera.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've added the reinventing-the-wheel given the response to (3) to indicate you don't want answer which are anywhere near BNF.

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to learning something new albeit. So feel free to talk of BNF, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## operator module

```
OPCODES = {
    "+": lambda lhs, rhs: lhs + rhs, ...
```

The lambdas are nice enough, they get the job done.
We could have just mentioned
[operator.add](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add),
floordiv, and so on.

## ints are floats

```
def _eval_op(
    lhs: Union[int, float], ...
```

Well, ok, clearly an `int` is not a `float`, nor does it inherit.
But rather than writing e.g. `lhs: int | float,`
[Pep-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower)
explains that

> when an argument is annotated as having type `float`, an argument of type `int` is acceptable

So prefer to shorten such annotations, as `int` is implicit.

## short docstring

The docstring for `eval_postfix_expr()` is lovely.
You lamented the repetition of longish docstrings.
Maybe include the operators by reference?
That is, refer the interested reader
over to `OPCODES`, which could have its *own* docstring.
And then a one-liner of "+ - * / // % ^" suffices.

It goes on to comment on ValueError, suggesting
that's the only Bad Thing that could happen.
Maybe any error that gets raised is self explanatory,
and doesn't need a mention?
Or maybe enumerate the others here, such as ZeroDivisionError.

Too bad there's no `i` operator.
This turns out to be a very poor substitute:

```
print((-1) ** .5)
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
```

## unary minus

```
        if tok.isdigit():
```

It makes me sad that `"3 -1 +"` won't parse,
since `"-".isdigit() == False`

I agree with @vnp's EAFP suggestion.

Directly accepting an input operand of `"-3.14"` seems simple enough,
without making me divide 314 by 100.

## silent error

```
        elif tok in OPCODES.keys():
            if len(stack) >= 2:
                rhs = stack.pop()
                lhs = stack.pop()
                stack.append(_eval_op(lhs, rhs, tok))
        else:
```

When presented with a short stack (bad input expression!)
we just silently move on without comment?!?

Worse, this could happen in the middle of an expression,
leading to a debugging nightmare.
(A dozen properly nested items, then short stack,
followed by another dozen properly nested items.
Where's the bad entry, we wonder?)

## long stack

Evaluating `"1 2 3 +"` will `return 5` but will leave `1` on the stack.
I feel this should be a fatal error reported to the user.

## DRY

`eval_prefix_expr()` is Too Long.
It should reverse, and then call `eval_postfix_expr()`.
Or both should call a common `_helper()`.

> I did not see a way to swap the operands for each operator.

Yeah, I see what you mean.
Define a `postfix_swap(a, b)` helper which does nothing
(identity function), and a `prefix_swap(a, b)` helper
which swaps its args, and pass in the swapper function
as part of the call.
Or maybe pass in `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` `arg_selector` tuples,
the indexes of `a` and `b`.

## simple tests

The custom `run_tests()` routine is nice.
We could tighten up a few things, like `{func_name:<{func_len}}`
is just `{func_name}`, and we could assign `func_name` just once
if we need it at all.

Consider phrasing this test in terms of `from unittest import TestCase`.

```
            assert rv == res
```

This equality test works for now.
But soon you'll want `self.assertAlmostEqual()`, I think.

## commutativity

I really do appreciate the emphasis on "simple" here.

```
    post_test_data = [ ...
        ("10 5 * 6 2 + /", 6.25),
        ...
    pre_test_data = [ ...
        ("/ * 10 5 + 6 2", 6.25),
```

Those say *nearly* the same thing.
But the one is not a reversal of the other.

In mathematics, addition over the reals commutes.
Similarly for multiplication.

In IEEE-754, addition is not commutative, nor is multiplication.
Order of evaluation matters.
We worry about catastrophic cancellation.
One way to avoid cumulative rounding errors in a long sum
is to order FP operands by magnitude and sum the little ones
before the big ones.

So consider ditching `pre_test_data`,
in favor of just reversing `post_test_data`.

## hypothesis

Consider writing a `postfix_to_infix()` converter,
whose parenthesized output you can just hand to `eval()`.
Now you have an "oracle" that knows the right answer.

With that in hand you can invite
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis)
to dream up random expressions of limited length,
and then you verify that the evaluations match.
I predict you will learn new things about
your code and about FP.

---

This code achieves most of its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Answer (score 2):

- Testing the first and last tokens is very dubious. It rejects a perfectly valid expression `42`, and accepts definitely invalid expressions like `2 *` and 1 2 3 +`.

  I strongly recommend to ditch this test, and handle problems as the evaluation goes on.
- `isdigit` test is redundant (and it also reject negative operants). The Grace Hopper's principle suggests

  ```
    try:
        stack.append(int(tok))
    except ValueError:
        # tok is not an integer, must be an operator
  ```

  Similarly, consider

  ```
     try:
         rhs = stack.pop()
         lhs = stack.pop()
         stack.append(eval_op(lhs, rhs, tok))
     except IndexError:
         # handle stack underrun
     except KeyError:
         # handle unknown operator
     except ZeroDivisionError:
         # which BTW is not handled in your code
  ```
- `stack` is too generic to my taste. I'd rather name it `operands`.

Comment: `# handle unknown operator` ==> Does `elif tok in OPCODES.keys()` not take care of that? How do you suggest handling `IndexError` and `ZeroDivisionError`?

Comment: @Harith Of course it does. The point is that EAFP is more Pythonic.